# Send request to server in background in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, background

In my iOS application i am sending request to server after time interval. I want to do this even if my app is in background or device is in sleep mode. Now my application sending request to server after time interval when its in fore ground.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [show us your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GoBusto I have not tried anything. I want to do this in background. I want to know the best way to do this in background.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that's not possible, even with background modes enabled.
with background mode, your app is just waked up when the system decide to.
you can't know when your code will be waked up...

if is not for Appstore, maybe there is a workaround with VoIP mode in backgrounds modes, search for background execution VoIP maybe you can find something.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are developing a VoIP app, you can have methods to do this.Please go to Apple Developers Documentation for references.

Background Execution:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

> Or you must pay attention that you need to publish your app on App Store or not.

- If you need to publish your app on App Store,so it's hard to do this,because Apple will not allow you to do this.Apple will reject your app if you use the code:`setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:`.When you develop the app,Xcode will tell you `Only VoIP apps can set KeepAliveTimeout`.